# Why is Rank of matrix [1, -0.8], [-0.8, 0.64] equal to 1?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Why the result is 1? there are two rows/column, that are not equal and can not be made by multiplying from an other.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3zd9.png)

Comment: because $(-0.8)*[1,-0.8]=[-0.8, 0.64]$

Comment: @Wolfram yes, true...thanks .... overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

The first column, multiplied by $-0.8$, is...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that multiplying the first row by $-0.8$ you obtain the second row.

Answer (score 1):

Because 2×2 determinant of your matrix is = 0

Therefore rank is $1$